# Can Fallibilism itself be fallible?

Tags: epistemology

It says: from IEP

> Fallibilism tells us that there is no conclusive justification and no
>   rational certainty for any of our beliefs or theses.

So, I am just applying fallibilist theses to fallibilism itself, when I do, then fallibilism becomes fallible, which means there is no such thing as fallibilism that we should believe (?)

Comment: @Geoffrey Thomas, thanks for your edits, may I know why it is not "the Fallibilism"? I also didn't want to put "the", in-front , but I assume this is "the only Fallible" theses we currently do have, So why not ''the"?

Comment: First, fallible knowledge is still better that no knowledge. Second, the fallibilist thesis, like any skeptical thesis, is not applicable to itself because it is not a universal claim. It is an inductive generalization from past experience. In a more precise form it states "no conclusive justification and no rational certainty for any of our beliefs or theses *has been produced so far, or can be plausibly produced by any means currently available*". Skeptics are doubters, they react and question what is offered, not offer something of their own for questioning. That is their limited function.

Comment: @Conifold - Your 'inductive' version of fallibilism makes sense, but this is not what is described in the question. What is described is a view that is itself fallible. I'd say the reason it is fallible is that it is not true, and so to note the fallibility of fallibilism would be important for a philosopher.  ,